# How to link javadoc to grails in SpringSource Tool Suite?

Tags: grails, javadoc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How do I link the javadocs for grails or groovy to SpringSource Tool Suite. I want the relevant javadocs to appear when I hover over things. I've been searching for a while but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is available in Groovy-Eclipse and should just be working.  Try this:

1. create an empty groovy script
2. add this text:

   ```
   /**
    * some javadoc
    * @return Something
    */
   def method() { }
   method()
   ```
3. now, hover over the method reference or declaration.
4. You should see nicely formatted javadoc.

It may be the case that you are failing to see javadoc on grails elements.  This should be working too, but can be a little more finicky.  In order for javadoc to work, the Grails tooling must be able to download the source of whatever library you are referencing.  Most of the time, this just happens.  But sometimes, you need to force it.  You can do this by selecting your Grails project, and right-clicking (see image below).

[image: download source]

Of course, it helps to make sure you have the latest Groovy-Eclipse and Grails-tooling installed (2.6.0 and 2.8.1 respectively).

Comment: Downloading the source jars got them to appear. I'm not sure how I missed that. Thanks a lot.